# oauth 2.0 - Resource owner password flow, can use windows login user credentials

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver3

I am using Identity Server 3 and using `InMemoryUsers` to keep my user/password info,

```
factory.UseInMemoryUsers(Users.Get());
```

For one of my client I'am using `ResourceOwner` password flow,

```
Flow = Flows.ResourceOwner,
```

Now, I am able to get `access token` by below setting, sending user/pass which we store In-Memory,

[image]

Now question is,
can I use `windows local users` credential in place of in-memory users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a service called `IUserService` which is responsible for getting user and its profile.

When you are using InMemory Users in fact you are using [InMemoryUserService](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/master/source/Core/Services/InMemory/InMemoryUserService.cs).

If you want to use windows local users, you need to implement your own `IUserService` and get users from windows and then register your service.

```
public CustomUserService : UserServiceBase
{
    public override Task AuthenticateLocalAsync(LocalAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        // You need to implement `GetUserFromWindows` to get users from windows local
        var user = GetUserFromWindows(context.UserName, context.Password);
        if (user != null)
        {
            context.AuthenticateResult = new AuthenticateResult(user.Subject, userDisplayName);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}


factory.UserService = new Registration<IUserService, CustomUserService>();
```